# Symfony, easyadmin filter via relation

Tags: symfony, filter, relation, easyadmin

I use Easyadmin bundle for the administrative part of the web-application and I use configuration like this:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Payment:
      class: App\Entity\Payment
      controller: App\Controller\CompanyController
      label: 'payments'
      list:
        item_permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_COMPANY_OWNER','ROLE_COMPANY_ACCOUNTANT']
        actions: ['show', '-delete', '-edit', '-new']
        collapse_actions: true
        title: 'Payments'
        filters:
          - { property: 'id', label: 'id' }
          - { property: 'type', label: 'type' }
          - { property: 'user', label: 'user' }
          ...
```

The problem is about I can't set filter via entity relation, like `{ property: 'user.company', label: 'company' }`, it throws exception that property does not exist or misconfigurated. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what is the relation between user and company i mean ManyToOne ManyToMany ...
checkout this https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/filters.html

Comment: Yes, relation between user and company is ManyToOne. I have read official docs, but I found nothing except to create completely custom filters

Answer (score 0):

you can use Static Filters (dql_filter Option)
The dql_filter option lets you define the conditions passed to the WHERE clause of the Doctrine query used to get the entities displayed in the list and search views.

for exemple

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        VipCustomers:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
                dql_filter: 'entity.budget > 100000'
        RegularCustomers:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
                dql_filter: 'entity.budget <= 100000'
```

and in your case i think you can do something like this.

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Payment:
      class: App\Entity\Payment
      controller: App\Controller\CompanyController
      label: 'payments'
      list:
        item_permission: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_COMPANY_OWNER','ROLE_COMPANY_ACCOUNTANT']
        actions: ['show', '-delete', '-edit', '-new']
        collapse_actions: true
        title: 'Payments'
        dql_filter: "user.company"
```